# socket.io (on message) triggers multiple times per message

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am learning react js and am making a chat app using socket.io
But I have run into this issue where it logs increasing number of times per message

[image: Messages]

This is my code for socketio stuff

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import io from "socket.io-client"
const socket = io("https://Wyvern-API.huski3.repl.co/api/chat")

socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('joined', { 'serverchannel': 120 })
    console.log("Connected")
})

function socketio() {
    const [hello, setCount] = useState("0")
    socket.on('message', (data) => {
        setCount(data.content)
        console.log(data.content)
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{hello}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default socketio
```

I used useEffect to stop it from spamming the ui during testing however I dont know how to address the root of this issue

[image: useeffect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all of your socketio listeners inside useEffect. React renders multiple times when any state or data changes, If your socket io listeners are outside useEffect , they will be added multiple times and so multiple triggers.

```
     import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import io from "socket.io-client"
    
    function socketio() {
        const [hello, setCount] = useState("0")
        const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

         useEffect(()=>{
           if(socket === null)
            {
                setSocket(io("https://Wyvern-API.huski3.repl.co/api/chat"))
            }
            if(socket)
            {
            socket.on('connect', () => {
            socket.emit('joined', { 'serverchannel': 120 })
            console.log("Connected")
            })

             socket.on('message', (data) => {
            setCount(data.content)
            console.log(data.content)
            })
        }
  },[socket])
           
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{hello}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default socketio
```